# i m saving the multiple images at a single time with differnt ID in database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> and it is saved but the issue is all the images have different auto
>   increment ids in database i want to save the images with the same ids
>   which is save at the same time,kindly guide me.

****strong text** the code is below;**

```
$field = Input::file('image');

$location = public_path('uploads/');
        foreach ($field as $k => $fd) {
            $filename = str_random(2).'-' . time() . "." . $fd->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fd->move($location , $filename);
            $product->image = $filename;
        }
        $user->save();
```

Comment: You can't have same auto increment id. Connect them via pivot table or another column in current table. Depending on how your database works.

Comment: it doesn't have another table or relation with other table when i saved the other data like name and description with these multiple images so it gives  duplicate data in database

Comment: I don't know what you are saving but if you have one name and description and multiple images for it then you should create separate table for images and connect it with id

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think bellow code helps you..
You can try.

$picture = '';

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

    $files = $request->file('image');
    foreach($files as $file){
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $picture = date('His').$filename;
        $destinationPath = base_path() . '\public\images';
        $file->move($destinationPath, $picture);
    }
}

if (!empty($product['images'])) {
    $product['images'] = $picture;
} else {
    unset($product['images']);
}
```